# writing a computer program in magma that finds a linear code and a specific automorphism group to the code.

Tags: automorphism-group

Given a binary finite field, and a vector space over this field, what command lines in magma can I use to find a self dual linear code and also find an automorphism group that acts on the code's coordinates 2-transitively?

Comment: You can use the recipe of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2642488/11619). Bec Note that you didn't specify the role to be played by the given subspace, leaving the question rather unclear. In general I doubt that you can have an algorithm for producing a self-dual code with such an automorphism group. Heck, I suspect that findin the automorphism group of a random code is difficult in general.

Comment: Hmm. I take that back. I'm no longer 100 % sure that a direct sum of extended Hamming codes has a 2-transitive automorphism group. It may have, but I'm too feverish to think straight.